# Google Maps not displaying in full width

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

Interesting situation. I'm developing a website where I want to display a google map on a page, as seen [here](http://dev.italianicecream.ca/contact/). It doesn't want to display, however if you shrink it to mobile view ('hit refresh after') it displays.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: If you show the code is better.....HTML, CSS Javascript

Answer (score 2):

in your file called second.css you have a rule called `#banner img` that is hiding all images inside that banner div.

```
#banner img{
position: absolute;
top: -999px;
left:-999px;
right: -999px;
bottom: -999px;
margin: auto;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
}
```

Try removing it and the map will show up.